# RDOSession.ExchangeMailboxServerName is null even after setting MAPIOBJECT

Tags: com, outlook-addin, outlook-redemption

The code below is run in the "StartupComplete" event handler of a COM Add-In.

All the values are returned except for **ExchangeMailboxServerName**.  The property is null.

I'm not sure what's wrong.

**CONNECTION STATUS INFORMATION**

[image]

**[image]OTE**: *In the code below ns.ExchangeMailboxServerName does contain the right value.*

[image: Message Store Properties from OutlookSpy]

```
            Outlook.NameSpace ns = null;


        try
        {
            ns = OutlookApp.Session;
            rdoSession = RedemptionLoader.new_RDOSession();


            rdoSession.MAPIOBJECT = ns.MAPIOBJECT;
            addressEntry = rdoSession.CurrentWindowsUser;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Address: " + addressEntry.Address);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Name: " + addressEntry.Name);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("NTAcountName: " + addressEntry.NTAccountName);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("SMTPAddress: " + addressEntry.SMTPAddress);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Country: " + addressEntry.Country);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Office Location:" + addressEntry.OfficeLocation);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(rdoSession.ExchangeMailboxServerName);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(rdoSession.ExchangeMailboxServerVersion);









        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            log.Error("Error in Startup: ", ex);
        }
```

Comment: Try the following in OotlookSpy - in Outlook, select one of the folders in the primary mailbox, click IMsgStore button. Right click, select `IMAPIProp::GetProps`, type PR_EMSMDB_SECTION_UID. In the IMsgStore window, rigth click on the PR_EMSMDB_SECTION_UID property, select `IMAPISession::OpenProfileSection`. Do you see the PR_PROFILE_HOME_SERVER property?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko  That property doesn't appear to exist.  I've edited my post to include a screen shot.

I am still able to get the name using the "OutlookApp.Session" property, so I should be fine.  I am  gathering this information in a separate thread and uploading it to a server.  I first instantiate RDOSession in the main thread at the class level so that it is always available.  Then I pass the the MAPIOBJECT to a new thread.  In the newly created thread, I instantiate a new RDOSession object and assign it the MAPIOBJECT that was passed in.   This method is correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. But you should pass the MAPIOBJECT only, not calling it on a secondary thread. Do you get the correct results on the main thread?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev
In the sample shown, RDOSession is being initialized in the Main thread ("AddinModule_AddinStartupComplete").   The value is not returned in either the main thread or in the other thread.

Comment: Well, if the `PR_PROFILE_HOME_SERVER` property doesn't exist I don't think any tool can help you. I'd suggest re-creating a profile and see how it works.

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev
Thanks, for that.  I did recreate the profile and still didn't see the property.   I'll just work with the value being returned by OutlookApp.Session.

Comment: What version of Outlook are you using? How about Exchange?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko
Exchange Sever Version = [15.20.2979.27]
Outlook Version: 16.0.0.10358

Comment: Are you connecting in eh PRC-over-HTTP or MAPI-over-HTTP mode?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko   MAPI-over-HTTP

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko
I've added screen shots of my Connection Status dialog

Comment: Hmmm... I don't know. Can you extract the server from the autodiscover XML?

Comment: I can definitely extract the server from the Application.Session object.  No problem there.
I am not dead in the water.  I was just trying to using the RDOSession object to get at the data.  It gives me everything else.

No need for further head scratching.  I don't know if this makes a difference, but the code is running inside of a VM.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko:  Yes, you're right.  The value IS in the autodiscover.xml.  I left that out of my response.

Consider this matter resolved.